# ListView Item shadow + custom selector

Tags: android, listview, layout, selector, shadow

I want to drop shadow at ListView item and also apply custom selector. But i don't know how to apply them at the same time..

Here is shadow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
              <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
        </shape>
    </item>
     <item 
         android:right="1dp" 
         android:bottom="2dp">        
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
              <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
        </shape>
     </item>         
</layer-list>
```

And custom selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item  
    android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@android:drawable/color/white" />  
<item 
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_background_blue" />  
</selector>
```

I have tried to apply selector to whole ListView `android:listSelector="@drawable/selector.xml"` and shadow to ListView item `android:background="@drawable/shadow.xml"` But in this case ListView item will have shadow but won't react to touch.

Thank you in advance

Comment: work .. thank you ^_^

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found solution. The reason why seletor doesn't appear is Android ListView structure. If you set background to List ItemView it overlaps Selector, so you can't see it. Solution is to make ItemView background transparent on Click.

Here is `listview_item_shadow.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
              <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
        </shape>
    </item>
     <item 
         android:right="1dp" 
         android:bottom="2dp">        
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
              <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
        </shape>
     </item>         
</layer-list>
```

Now you should use it in selector for ItemView! - `listview_item_backgroundstate.xml`
You need to set `listview_item_backgroundstate.xml` as background to your ListView item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"></item>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"></item>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/listview_item_shadow"></item>
</selector>
```

And at last you have to set `custom_selector.xml` as in `ListView`. `android:listSelector="@drawable/custom_selector.xml"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item  
    android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@android:drawable/color/white" />  
<item 
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_background_blue" />  
</selector>
```

For more info read this awesome [tutorial](http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/08/08/listview-tips-tricks-3-create-fancy-listviews/)